# UIAutomation: get_CurrentVerticalScrollPercent sometimes returns 0 after SetScrollPercent

Tags: winapi, microsoft-ui-automation

I find that using `SetScrollPercent()` then using `get_CurrentVerticalScrollPercent()` right after it *sometimes* (actually fairly often) returns 0 instead of the actual value it's at.  No error is returned.   I presume I'll have to add a delay or something, is there a way to ensure `SetScrollPercent()` is done before issuing `get_CurrentVerticalScrollPercent()` ?  This test was done on the Command Prompt of Windows 10.

Comment: Can you show a mini and reproducible sample?

Comment: I added Sleep(10) between the set and get, seems to work now.